# Python Script, Can't Create or Open Text File

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to open a file and write some text to it. I'm using Windows, and Python 3.8.7 (I tried 3.9.1 as well). When I am in a Windows command prompt, and run my script: "python filewrite.py", I get a print statement to let me know it actually ran, but no file is created.

When I open the interpreter by calling "python" and then copy/paste my code from my script, a file is created with the appropriate text in it.

I've tried opening and closing files both ways, using "with" and just "f.open", but neither has worked. I believe it is related to my setup on Windows, but I've tried uninstalling every version of Python and reinstalling, and no luck.

Tried it this way

```
f = open("F:\\Coding\\file.txt", 'w+')
f.write('Python loves you!')
f.close()
print("We tried")
```

and this way:

```
with open("F:\\Coding\\file.txt", 'w+') as f:
    f.write('Python loves you!')
print("We tried")
```

Neither work. I've also tried it without the absolute path, which has the same behavior. I've tried it with and without the '+', I've tried creating the file first and appending, with no luck. The fact that it works in the interpreter, and not when run as a script is my biggest clue as to what is wrong. I actually want to incorporate writing to a file in a more complicated script, but I can't even do this simple thing first. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the directory is writable? Can you read a file from the same location?

Comment: I can read a file from the same location; I checked and it did say the folder was read and execute only, which is kinda weird because I'm able to create files no problem and, and like I said, the interpreter could also create the file.

Comment: Actually, I've forced it to make certain I have full control of the directory, and still the same result.

Comment: Can you try to read it in Python _after_ you've written to it? Make sure it doesn't exist first. Then run your code that writes to the file and then reads from the file and prints the contents. If it works, you're looking in the wrong place or you can't see the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue. Turns out my Comodo Antivirus was auto-containing the created files. I told the antivirus to ignore that area for auto-containment, and my scripts can now create files.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Webs64 and welcome!

I ran your code as follows on my MAC

```py
with open("/Users/person/Documents/file.txt", 'w+') as f:
    f.write('Python loves you!')
print("We tried")
```

and was successful in creating the file and writing the `python loves you!` to it.

Can you try without the F and double (\)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To ask for clarifications to a question, please add a comment instead of an answer. If you do not yet have the [reputation](/help/privileges) to do so, please [answer](/help/how-to-answer) other [well-asked questions](/help/how-to-ask) that do not require clarifications to build up your reputation.

Comment: Ryan, I tried that with no success. I've tried it without the direct path as well, using just the "file.txt" and I have the same results: works in the interpreter, not in the script.

Comment: @Webs64, could you add os.listdir(), for the directory you are trying to write too, to your script? Then run it from command line? Maybe the file is being created but is hidden?

Comment: @Ryan Burch Sadly, this is not the case, as I confirmed I'm viewing hidden files, and it's not there.